# How can I call change resetButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {} to call a method?

Tags: c#

I have this code that I shortened for this question:

```
resetButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
{
   var response = await X.DisplayAlert("X","Y","Yes", "No");
};
```

I would like to break it out into a method so I tried this:

```
resetButton.Clicked += resetButtonClicked;

protected void resetButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var response = await X.DisplayAlert("X","Y","Yes", "No");
}
```

But this does not work as I need to specify the method to be async. Can someone give me some advice how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This outta work.

```
resetButton.Clicked += resetButtonClicked;

protected async Task resetButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var response = await X.DisplayAlert("X","Y","Yes", "No");
}
```